# How do I run Maven 2?

Tags: maven-3

I have installed Maven 2.2.1-5 via the Ubuntu Software Center.  How do I run it?

Why does it not appear in Ubuntu Software Center / Installed Software?

(Ubuntu Software Center / Get Software shows it is installed.)

I am on Maverick (10.10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Terminal type `mvn --version` to see if it runs.  If it does then it's probably installed.